# Wrap tensorflow multiply with Lambda

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I am trying to do the simplest thing (so I think): Wrap the `tf.math.multiply` with keras `Lambda` layer in TF 2.0:

```
def my_mult(xx, yy):
    return tf.math.multiply(xx, yy)
```

For two inputs (with broadcasting)

```
>>>_in
<tf.Tensor 'conv2d_3/Identity:0' shape=(None, 32, 32, 256) dtype=float32>
>>>_in_s
<tf.Tensor 'activation_3/Identity:0' shape=(None, 256) dtype=float32>
```

the following works:

```
>>>tf.math.multiply(_in,_in_s)
<tf.Tensor 'Mul:0' shape=(None, 32, 32, 256) dtype=float32>
>>>_in * _in_s
<tf.Tensor 'mul_1:0' shape=(None, 32, 32, 256) dtype=float32>
```

but none of the bellow seems to work:

```
Lambda(my_mult)(_in,_in_s)
...TypeError: my_mult() missing 1 required positional argument: 'yy'

Lambda(my_mult)((_in,_in_s))
...TypeError: my_mult() missing 1 required positional argument: 'yy'
```

Answer (score 0):

For now I "solved" it by changing `my_mult` to:

```
def my_mult(ins):
    return tf.math.multiply(ins[0], ins[1])
```

and then call:

`Lambda(my_mult)((_in,_in_s))`

If anyone have nicer solution he is welcome to share.

Comment: You could unpack `ins` in the function. `x, y = ins` and then `return tf.math.multiply(x,y)`

Comment: @Andy Sure, but the main improvment I am looking for is to actually be able to send two different arguments to `Lambda`

Comment: Keras itself uses your workaround in [their examples](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/layers/core.py#L566) :(